# JS tables event handling

Tags: javascript, onchange

I am trying to build a table that shows numbers stored in drop downlists and calculates the number of all drop down list values calculated together "onchange"

Everything works fine however the total is not appearing in the box. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `#total` element a form field? If not, `.value` won't work, use `.innerText`

Comment: Also, be sure you're using `parseInt` or some variant to ensure your `.value` is a number

Comment: @helion3 yes, it was a form field. I have edited it but it still isn't working

Comment: Did you change your code? You still need `.value` the options...

Comment: @helion3 doesn't seem to work with .value either

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle please ? It would help a lot

Comment: It would work with `.value`. Try inspecting the values you're getting and make sure you're checking for `Val` being empty, that won't parse to an int. Also, I meant `.textContent`, `innerText` won't work consistently across browser. Demo: http://codepen.io/helion3/pen/lCHBs

Comment: Try to put together a working example using jsfiddle.com or codepen.io. It's easier to see a live example we can fiddle with. Creating your own reduced test case often helps solve the problem anyway

Comment: That's a ton of code to sort through, but `eachDropDown.onchange` isn't going to work because you're not actually assigning the onchange event to a select box. The `eachDropDown` is a variable set in a loop for the result of the .appendChild method. You need to assign the onchange event to each selectbox. try `mark.onchange = function(){` - http://jsbin.com/hodop/2/

Comment: @helion3 thank you so much for your time, think i can finish it off from here